# Can't scroll to top in listview

Tags: android, listview

I tried lot of methods for scroll to top in listview.But nothing worked.

This is my code (Shortened version):

```
public void placeRandomUsers(final String search) {
    Randoms randoms=new Randoms(randomsList);   
    randomsAdapter=new RandomsAdapter(this,randoms);
    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    listView.setAdapter(randomsAdapter);
    loadRandomUsers(search);

}

private void loadRandomUsers(String search) {
       for (int i=0; i<result.size(); i++) {
        randomsList.add(new Random(result.get(i).getAsJsonObject(),0));
       }
    ((RandomsAdapter) randomsAdapter).notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Example:

```
private void loadRandomUsers(String search) {
       for (int i=0; i<result.size(); i++) {
        randomsList.add(new Random(result.get(i).getAsJsonObject(),0));
       }
    ################SCROLL AREA#################
    ((RandomsAdapter) randomsAdapter).notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

These are what I placed particularly to `SCROLL AREA`:

```
listView.setSelectionAfterHeaderView();


listView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);



listView.post( new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
         listView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
    }
});
```

Xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:background="#FFFFFF"
        >
    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            />

</LinearLayout>
```

And items:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:paddingBottom="4dp"
              android:paddingTop="4dp"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:src="@drawable/twitter"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
        android:paddingRight="4dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tweet"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#0A0A14" 
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bio"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#474747" 
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:textSize="11sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"/>



    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView
 android:id="@+id/image1"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"

 android:src="@drawable/anchor" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Why these methods are not working ?

Comment: What isn't working about it? What is it doing?

Comment: Your adapter doesn't have any data when you try to scroll it. Try doing one of the things you tried after you call notifyDataSetChanged and your adapter actually has data.

Comment: @zgc7009 I also tried it but not worked.